# Python dictionary - without " " or ' ' around the values

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I need to create Python dictionaries where a value is not enclosed with " " or ' '.

For example, I need the *yes* value to have no quote marks around it.

I have
`{'start': 1, 'end': 6, 'id': 1, 'ws': 'yes'}`

but I need
`{'start': 1, 'end': 6, 'id': 1, 'ws': yes}`

I tried making it a string, but then couldn't convert it back (it's a nest of dictionaries and lists).
Is there a hack for this?
Thank you

Comment: It's `False` -- Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: What do you mean by "the *false* value"?  There is no such constant in Python; this would be a variable name -- and undefined.  Did you mean the Boolean constant `False`?

Comment: It's not a constant/Boolean for Python and it has to be lower case. The name of the value (false in this case) is irrelevant in a way, it's the quotations that are problematic

Comment: That's not possible. There's no value in Python whose representation is `false` without quotes.

Comment: Dictionaries contain values, not literals. Quoting is just the way that strings are shown when you print the dictionary. What is the actual value that should be in that dictionary element?

Comment: ... You could create an object whose representation is `false` without quotes, but that requirement would be a little baffling.

Comment: What are you going to do with the resulting dictionary with no quotes?

Comment: Are you trying to create JSON with `false` in it? The `json` library will automatically convert Python `False` to JSON `false`.

Comment: Your last edit makes no sense. You still talk about `false`, but the dictionary says `yes`.

Comment: This is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What *exactly* are you trying to do here? What's the big picture?

Comment: As @khelwood said, you can define a class, and give it a `__repr__` method that returns the string `yes`. Then put an instance of that class in the dictionary.

Comment: But you won't be able to convert it back from a string, because the Python parser doesn't know about this class.

Comment: This is all helpful, thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

```py
input = {'start': 1, 'end': 6, 'id': 1, 'ws': 'false'}

for key in input.keys():
    if input[key] == "false":
        input[key] = False
    elif input[key] == "true":
        input[key] = True

print(input)
```

Result:

`{'start': 1, 'end': 6, 'id': 1, 'ws': False}`